# How to find a normal subgroup in the $p-$group of order $p^5$ other than center?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a non-abelian $p$-group of the order $|G|=p^5$ such that Frattini Subgroup $\Phi(G)$, Commutator Subgroup $G'$ and Center $Z(G)$ of $G$ are equal and Rank($G$)=$3$, Exponent($G$)=$p$ (there exist unique such group but i do not know why?).

I wish to find a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ of the order $p^2$ other than $Z(G)$.

**My try:** Clearly $G=\langle x,y,z\rangle$ for some $x,y,z\in G$. Atleast one of the subgroups $H_1=\langle x,y\rangle,H_2=\langle y,z\rangle$ and $H_3=\langle x,z\rangle$ is not of the order $p^2$. Suppose $|H_1|\neq p^2$, then $|H_1|=p^3$ or $p^4$ and $H_1$ contains the center $Z(G)$.

Now I am unable to proceed.

Comment: Calculate $\;G/Z(G)\;$ , which cannot be cyclic non-trivial ( and thus its order is at least $\;p^2\;$), calculate its center and pull back to get a normal subgroup of $\;G\;$ different from the center...and in fact, containing the center.

Comment: Since $Z(G)=\Phi(G)$ and Rank($G$)=3, $G/Z(G)$ is elementary abelian and $|G/Z(G)|=p^3$. So $Z(G/Z(G))=G/Z(G)$.Now?

Comment: I completely forgot about the data $\;\Phi(G)=G\;$, so the above doesn't work...But now that I read more carefully: you say you want to find a normal subgroup *of order* $\;p^2\;$ *other than* $\;Z(G)\;$ ...so is it a given that $\;|\Phi(G)|=|Z(G)|=p^2\;$ ?

Comment: Given that Rank$(G)$=$3$ and $Z(G)=G'=\Phi(G)$. So $|G/(\Phi(G))|=p^3$ and hence $Z(G)=G'=\Phi(G)$ is elementary abelian subgroup of the order $p^2$.

Comment: The statement $|x|$, $|y|$ and $|z|$ are greater than $p$ is wrong. They are al equal to $p$, because you are told that $G$ has exponent $p$.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited. Thanks @DerekHolt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G = \langle x,y,z \rangle$. Since $Z(G)= [G,G]$ is generated by the three commutators $[x,y]$, $[x,z]$ and $[y,z]$, we may assume that $Z(G)=\langle t,u \rangle$ with $[x,y]=t$, $[x,z]=u$.

If $[y,z]=1$, then take $N= \langle y,t \rangle$.

If $[y,z] = t^iu^j \ne 1$, then $[y,z] = [x,y^iz^j]$ and we can take $N = \langle y^iz^j, t^iu^j \rangle$.